# How to get data on given Lat, Lon within specific distance in ArcGIS REST Services?

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api, arcgis-server

I need to get nearby data within some radius on given latitude and longitude from ArcGIS endpoints. How I can do that using ArcGIS REST Services?

Answer (score 2):

You did not specified what information and/or what service, so I will asume that you  want to query features of a `FeatureService`.

If this is the case, you need to specified at least this parameter to achieve what you want:

- `geometry`, the input geometry, in your case `geometry=lon,lat`
- `geometryType` the type of your input geometry, in your case `geometryType=esriGeometryPoint`
- `inSR`, the SRID of the input geometry, in your case `inSR=4326`
- `spatialRel`, the relation of the features to retrieve with the input geometry, here you might have a couple of choices as an example `spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects`
- `distance`, the buffer distance, as an example `distance=X`
- `units`, the unit of the distance parameter, as an example `unist=esriSRUnit_Kilometer`

  [ArcGIS REST Doc - Query Feature Layer](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/query-feature-service-layer-.htm)

Comment: I meant about services from ArcGIS REST Services Directory, in my case, I am trying to check one of the services under https://maps.helcom.fi/arcgis/rest/services/MADS/Biodiversity/MapServer    . .  .afte applying your suggestions, I get empty features

Comment: @cabeson it worked finally with geometry={14.42,55.42}  . . thanks for help

Comment: Glad it help you.

Comment: the same parameters are not working for other API https://maps.helcom.fi/arcgis/rest/services/MADS/Biodiversity/MapServer/295 . Can you tell me what can be a fix for it?

Comment: @cabeson , can you please guide me on the second problem?

Comment: Pass me the url of the one that you try and work out, I need to check something

Comment: @cabeson, URL was too long to attach in a comment. I have posted below as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://maps.helcom.fi/arcgis/rest/services/MADS/Pressures/MapServer/200/query?where=1%3D1&text=&objectIds=&time=&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=false&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&having=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&historicMoment=&returnDistinctValues=false&queryByDistance=&returnExtentOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&quantizationParameters=&f=pjson&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&geometry=%7B14.42,55.42%7D&inSR=4326&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&distance=10&units=esriSRUnit_Kilometer) worked for me. Now trying to execute https://maps.helcom.fi/arcgis/rest/services/MADS/Biodiversity/MapServer/295

Comment: I think the problem is the type of layer, and that does not support advanced queries. The answer that I give you is to request features, so for example it works with Feature Layer (like layer 203), that also support advanced queries. The one that is giving you trouble, layer 295, is a Raster Layer. View the properties of both layers and check what I am mention to you.

Comment: Layer 295 Supports Query With Distance: true as mentioned on Service directory; that is what I only need when I need to provide lat and lon with distance to fetch data. Can you come up with valid unadvanced query parameters for 295?